# Magento2: Best way to have a desktop and mobile template in a module

Tags: magento2, module, mobile

I am doing a module in magento 2 and I need to have separate phtml files for desktop and mobile respectively.

How can I do that? Do I need to create a mobile template, that override the module and use user agent rules in the admin ?

If it is the the best way, how can I override the `module/view/frontend/template/mytemplate.phtml` ?

I am a bit lost here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean make a website mobile reponsive or having a whole new layout?

Comment: I need a new layout because will have different functionality (the mobile will interact with the camera)

Comment: I'm sorry , have never seen that before. I mean you could just create another page with a Controller and then use Javascript to determine the device and redirect to the other page. Or you can just have 1 big template fille where you have a Desktop and a Mobile div in it and just hide/show the right div with css and media screen. Hmmn but i don't see a clean solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different options but at the end to keep it easier to understand from the magento admin I added 2 themes desktop and mobile that override the module.
I didn't needed to change the layout configuration in the modules.

**module**

> app/code/acme/modulename/view/frontend/templates/main.phtml

**desktop**

> app/design/acme_default/templates/main.phtml

**mobile**

> app/design/acme_mobile/templates/main.phtml

Then added the acme_default at **admin->content->design->configuration->edit** Applided Theme

and added a new user agent rule for mobile with acme_moble